# Rails association design, has_many through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, has-many-through, has-many

I am working on a dummy rails application; as part of my programming skills self education. And I am feeling a bit stuck with the rails association concept as I am not sure which is the right way to go for.

In this exercise I want to have the following models:
- User
- Project
- Team

And I would like to create the following associations:
- `User` has many `Project`
- `Project` has many `User` through `Team`
- `Team` has many `User` through `Project`

The idea is that a user can create a project and on-board or invite other users. Before the project  get saved, thanks to a `before_create`, the application will create a new team `Project_Team` with the `User` and the other users he added during the Project creation process.

Of course I am not talking about model dependencies as i will tackle this point once I have the right associations set.

I wrote the following code but I could not get the association, explained above, to working as expected:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :project
  has_many :team, through :project
end

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :team
  has_many :user, through :team
end

class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
  has_many :user, through :project
end
```

Many thanks for your future help (and tolerance for the "might-be" bad code above).

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pluralize `has_many` associations but keep your `belongs_to` singular. You're also missing colons after the `through`. Your associations should be:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :projects
  has_many :teams, through: :projects
end

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :team
  has_many :users, through: :team
end

class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
  has_many :users, through: :project
end
```

Check out the [Rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) for more info.